# I can't submit project on heroku

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, heroku, maven-plugin

Can anybody help me? I'm trying to upload a project in spring boot very simple, but I'm not succeeding, it doesn't let the project upload because of this error that appears, could someone help me?

MAVEN: apache-maven-3.1.0

JAVA: 17

------------------

Apache Maven 3.1.0

Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.1.0

Java version: 17, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17

------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.prestes</groupId>
    <artifactId>crudaplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>crudaplication</name>
    <description>Projeto em Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
         <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.informix/informix-jdbc-complete -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.50.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I8Md.png)

l Need Help please.................

Comment: Are you  using a procfile?

Comment: What would procfile be? I'm trying to manually upload the heroku cli using the commands that appear in the documentation

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: Review your log to understand the error. It is very common: You are deploying a java 17 application in a server which don't have java 17. In heroku, the procfile is the solution

Comment: To improve your question for future readers, change it to something like: How to set jdk version in heroku. Also copy and paste the text of your error log and attach it using markdown https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/d0753aa313676e260df416e3b50b7fbc

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the required java version with one of these methods:

#### system.properties

According to the official docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version you just need to create a file **system.properties** close to your pom.xml with the required version (17 in your case):

```
java.runtime.version=15
```

#### heroku maven plugin

According to the official docs:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin
- https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-maven-plugin

Using the heroku maven plugin you can set advanced heroku configurations like the jdk version:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <appName>${heroku.appName}</appName>
        <jdkVersion>17</jdkVersion>
        <processTypes>
          <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.example.Main</web>
        </processTypes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```